google authorization for youtube analytics api (brand or manager role)
so i've been working on a code to get audience retention using aouth2 youtube analytics api, while granting access whether to my youtube channel (manager role) or sub channel (owner) with my linked google account it returns 403 error
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?ids=channel%id&startDate=2022-01-01&endDate=2024-12-31&metrics=audienceWatchRatio&filters=video%3D%3Did&dimensions=elapsedVideoTimeRatio&alt=json returned "Forbidden". Details: "[{'message': 'Forbidden', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]">
it should get the audience retention, it works if i grant access with the owner's account but for sub channels it doesn'r work at all
thank you
